# SPOSiteScript does not create the target site column correctly

Tags: sharepoint-online, sitedesign

I used a column definition from where a note Site Column had "Allow unlimited length in document libraries "  = Yes
But when a site is created with the site design, the resulting note Site Column shows "Allow unlimited length in document libraries "  = No

Is there anything else need to be done for this to work?
Who do you tell if this is a bug?

```
{
"verb": "createSiteColumnXml",
"schemaXml": "<Field DisplayName=\"DPC Notes\" Type=\"Note\" Required=\"FALSE\" ID=\"{70ad6b94-13dd-43ac-947a-6634aef36588}\"
                          StaticName=\"DPCNotes\" Name=\"DPCNotes\" Group=\"ECGmc\" Description=\"DPC Notes (typed by DPC users while producing the document)\"
                          AppendOnly=\"TRUE\" NumLines=\"6\" RichText=\"TRUE\" Customization=\"\" CustomFormatter=\"\" EnforceUniqueValues=\"FALSE\" Indexed=\"FALSE\"
                          RestrictedMode=\"TRUE\" RichTextMode=\"Compatible\" IsolateStyles=\"FALSE\" UnlimitedLengthInDocumentLibrary=\"TRUE\"  />",
"pushChanges": true
}
```

Thank you much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I test with this json,it works well:

```
 {
                      "verb": "createSiteColumnXml",
                      "schemaXml": "<Field Type=\"Note\" DisplayName=\"siteColumnMutipleText\" Required=\"FALSE\" EnforceUniqueValues=\"FALSE\" Indexed=\"FALSE\" UnlimitedLengthInDocumentLibrary=\"TRUE\" NumLines=\"6\" RichText=\"TRUE\" RichTextMode=\"FullHtml\" IsolateStyles=\"TRUE\" Sortable=\"FALSE\" Group=\"Custom Columns\" ID=\"{9b5e375a-44ef-405b-8316-fe136a841775}\" SourceID=\"{b62d1450-8e6f-4be7-84a3-f6600fd6cc14}\" StaticName=\"siteColumnMutipleText\" Name=\"siteColumnMutipleText\" Version=\"1\"></Field>",
                      "pushChanges": true
                      }
```

[image]

Comment: My mistake, I actually wanted it to be "No" so it will be just one textarea. BTW do you know if there is a way to incorporate the "Edit form" set of one Document library to the site script?